# 'laravel' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to install laravel 5.4 on my system, I have followed steps to install it but I'm not sure where I'm doing mistake. 
I'm using windows 10, When I run command

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

It shows error "Content length mismatch".

```
laravel new myproject

'laravel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

php -v
output :

```
 PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 18:51:14) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
 Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

When I run this command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

It shows this error

```
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Handshake timed out
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

Also I have added "C:\Users\AAMIR\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin" to Path variable in environment variables.
Now I'm stuck on this issue. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Installing Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO its better if you use the other option:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: I tried that command but it gave me this error.........................The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Handshake timed out
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Comment: pls check that you have all the extensions required by composer enabled, in php.ini. In particular mode check for SSL extensions. Have you upgraded php after installing composer? try to reinstall composer, it checks for all the extensions it needs

Comment: I installed composer after upgrading php